# How GNU treats a failure indicator from main

Tags: c++, c

I write a simple case to see how my system treats a failure indicator from main.
But nothing happened. I really want to know what's the difference between return 0 and return -1.

```
int main()
{
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Upvoted unexplained downvote.

Comment: Note that on POSIX systems, only the lower 8 bits of the exit status are actually returned to the parent process due to the behavior of how the [`wait(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) system call works (see the notes on the `WEXITSTATUS` macro).

Answer (score 3):

That depends on what your "system" is. If you just run a program then this value is ignored.

The only time this is used is if your program is part of a larger workflow where your program's failure matters. For example, a makefile (or a C++ IDE) will stop building the program if there's a failure in one of the steps. This failure is signaled by an error code from `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

most of the times, the return value in main has no use, traditionally, we return 0 to indicate the program is success, especially in Windows. But in Linux, we often have a chain of programs, which means the second program's state depends on the first one's result. At that time, the return value has its position.

So, no matter what the return value is, most of the times its depends on your design, and it means nothing to system.

Hope that can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have compiled an executable named a.out, consider:

```
$ ./a.out                 # ignore the value returned from main
$ ./a.out && echo success # check the value returned from main
$ ./a.out || echo failure
```

In the second and third case, the echo will only occur if `a.out` is successful or not, respectively, where success is defined as returning zero from main.  This is a convention that may be more clear with the following syntax:

```
if ./a.out; then
  echo a.out returned zero from main
else
  echo a.out returned non-zero from main
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `main()` is available:

1. To the shell, if the shell started it, as `$status` etc, depending on which shell you're using.
2. To the program that started it, via the `status` variable pointed to by the argument to `wait()`. See [*man 2 wait()*](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait).

GNU has precisely nothing do to with it.

Answer (score 0):

If using the bash shell (or similar), you can show the return value of the last command executed with `echo $?`. Sample bash terminal session:

```
$false
$echo $?
1
$true
$echo $?
0
$
```

On other systems the return value will be accessed differently. On DOS or Windows the return value can be checked with the ERRORLEVEL command or %ERRORLEVEL% variable.